# When i try to query django model by positive small integer field i get error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When i run the following code i get the error  "TypeError: Field 'app' expected a number but got <AppChoices.SUK: 1>"

```
class Category(models.Model):
      class AppChoices(models.Choices):
            ASK_EMBLA = 0
            SUK = 1

      ---


class SellerReview(models.Model):

 ------
    app = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
          choices=Category.AppChoices.choices, 
             default=Category.AppChoices.ASK_EMBLA)

    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

-----

class RentPostDetailSearializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ---

    def get_posted_by_brief(self, obj: RentPost):
    
           -----

    rating = 0

    ratings = list(poster_profile.seller_reviews.filter(
        app=Category.AppChoices.SUK).values_list("rating", flat=True)) #---> issue here 

    if ratings:
        rating = sum(ratings)/len(ratings)

    ---
```

Don't know why is this happening even though the App choices are integers and supposed to be numbers

Comment: If the values are integers, you should use `models.IntegerChoices` instead of `models.Choices`. With the latter, the value of each enum entry is not equivalent to an integer.

Comment: @solarissmoke  yup this works. You can post it as an answer and i will accept it. don't know how i missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are integers, you should use `models.IntegerChoices` instead of `models.Choices`.

Unless using the `IntegerChoices` base class specifically, `Enum` members [are not integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons).